# Why do programmers use component property in react routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I'm studying react nowadays. I found that programmers usually use component property when routing in react. So, for route a component named Menu, they write code like

```
<Route exact path='/menu' component={ Menu } />
```

rather than

```
<Route exact path='/menu'> <Menu /> </Route>
```

I think the second way is much more convenient when giving `props` to `Menu` component. So my question is, what is the benefit of writing code as the first way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It is all about the usecase. There are following ways we can declare a route:

1. **component**

   ```
   <Route to="/home" component={Home} />
   ```

   One add routes this way when one doesn't want to have the control to pass any props to the Component, simple passing the Component Object to the route as a prop.
2. **render**

   ```
   <Route to="/home" render={props => <Home {...props} />} />
   ```

   One add routes this way when one want to have the control to pass any props to the Component and even update the existing component props.
3. **children**

   ```
   <Route exact path='/home'> <Home/> </Route>
   ```

   This is another way to pass the route component as a child to the Route component. you can again pass the props or maybe wrap the component into another component or some html structure.

It is simply a developer's choice to pick one for its solution. Developer these days use many methods or frameworks to induce routing in the react app. I personally like the first one, as it is clean, ensures prop-types and give warnings on any violation and also I don't have a use case or prop passing on route level.

Comment: please do accept the answer if it works, and helpful for you, thanks!